# Overwrite/Update MobileConnect Contact Key?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, contactbuilder

Is it possible to update or overwrite the Contact Key attribute for MobileConnect contacts?

Basically we would like to keep the current contacts with their subscription statuses and history, but only to change the Contact Key from the existing one (custom backend ID) to a new one (Salesforce Contact ID).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question: Is it possible to update or overwrite the Contact Key attribute for MobileConnect contacts?**

**Answer: No**

**Explanation:**  Contact Keys are immutable. Even after you delete your contacts, they remain in the system (back end) as SFMC keeps are record of all your contacts for compliance reasons.

I have seen special situations where you can engage professional services for a Subscriber Key migration (in email studio). May be you might be able to do this for the contact key in contact builder.

Comment: You can delete them with the REST API.

Comment: Mentioned by @AdamSpriggs deletion method: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132859/remove-users-from-all-contacts-in-marketing-cloud (author @EliotHarper). I am not sure if it is soft or hard delete.

Comment: I see..this complicates things quite a bit for us. Thank you for sharing your knowledge guys!