# Find an email address in all data extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I need to find all the data extensions where a particular subscriber/ email address exists. Is there a way I can obtain that list? using API or any query?

Because of this upcoming GDPR thing, we are required to develop all kinds of processes

Comment: I only know how to delete a contact from all data extensions which are sendable, aswell as contact list and subscriber list. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/210050/52639

Answer (score 1):

I've built something like this for a client. It took several weeks.

The gist is that you can retrieve all Data Extensions and Data Extension Fields via SOAP API and store them in Data Extensions. I used a Script Activity and WSProxy for this.

From there, I wrote another series of Script Activities that generate a Query Activities for a set of Subscribers for every Data Extension in the inventory of Data Extensions.

Once I had all of the Query Activities created, I just executed them all in an Automation.

The client just needed to populate a Data Extension of subscribers to search and kick off the process.

The end result was a Data Extension of Subscriber Keys and they Data Extensions they were in.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually take Backup of your Org using Eclipse and then search the target email address. This is the easiest way.

Comment: Question is about Marketing Cloud, not CRM