# Deleting Contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have enabled the feature which allows the deletion of Contacts in Salesforce Marketing Cloud. How is the featured used if we'd want to delete 100s of 1000s of records in one go? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The REST Api allows for mass deletion so long as you know your contact keys/ids.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/DeleteByContactIDs.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/DeleteByContactKeys.htm

Do these Api endpoints not meet your needs?

Comment: Thanks for sharing. We've enabled the internal mass-delete. From there we're able to select individual records or lists. We have records surfaced from CRM via the Connector but they've not been deployed to so not on AllSubscribers. The records are just visible as Contacts with no associated list so struggling to know how to mass-delete (from within SFMC).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this still needs an answer but here is what I am gathering.

You are importing contacts and/or accounts into your Marketing Cloud via the connector. They are taking up your contacts in MC even though you have not sent to them, hence why they are not in All Subscribers.

You will have to do a few things for this to work.

1. Go to MobileConnect > Manage > Contacts
   This will take you to a MobileConnect Contacts page, looks very similar to the Contact Builders All Contacts page except that there are two tabs. One called All Contacts and another called Lists.
2. Click on Lists tab and then click on New List, create list from Filter.

To get the full list of contacts just use a filter where Contact Key is not null and run.

This should create a list of all contacts in your MC. You can then query the list against whatever you would like such as All Subscribers and do a where not exists clause on that list.

This should give you contactkeys that are contacts but not in All Subscribers.

Here is where the caveats are.

1. If you want to delete them as contacts in MC then you can but if you are using the connector and the record still exists in CRM then it will just resynch it back after the suppression period. (Note you will want to make sure you have a suppression period set up in your contacts setting that fits your needs. For example in my org we have it set to 0 days)
2. If you do make a decision to delete then you will have to create a DE's or lists out of the contacts you want to delete. Note that delete function in contact builder limits 1,000,000 records in a DE so if you have more you will have to create multiple lists. So if 3 million, that's 3 lists of a million each and you will have to run the delete on each.

Comment: There's actually another method, which seems to work even if the client does not have MobileConnect enabled in their instance. By going to ContactBuilder > MobileLists you will be able to create the list with all the contacts, export it, and then re-import it into a Data Extensions of your choice to use via API. Still, there should be an easier way of getting a Data Extension with all Contacts to just copy the External Key and use it in the API call. I hope I was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_delete_contact.htm&type=5

As referenced from: [Remove users from All contacts in marketing cloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132859/remove-users-from-all-contacts-in-marketing-cloud)

Comment: Thanks, Tom. I did notice this. However, my Contacts are not on a list or in a data extension so struggling to identify how to mass-delete.

Comment: Do you know which contacts you want to delete?  If so, you'll want to run a query to get those -- or do a file import into a data extension with the subscribers you want to delete.

Comment: The Contacts are only visible in All Contacts. They've been surfaced from CRM via the Connector. They've never been deployed to so on no list.

Comment: @TonEco Do you know which subscribers you want to delete?  Have a list?  Or is it just all the subscribers that are associate with a synchronized DE?  Either way - you'll need to add them to a list or DE to delete them.  To my knowledge, SFMC didn't make them deletable from the All Contacts table on purpose but requires an intermediate list/data extension to facilitate the deletion.  That's a good fail-safe.

Comment: Thanks, Tom, It would be all Contacts associated with the sync. If we delete Contacts from a data extension and they exists in more than one DE will they still be deleted from the systems? Thanks

Comment: You could export them from a Data Extension, and import them into a list, then delete the list (making sure to tick the box that says delete from ALL lists)