# Deleting a Mobile Connect instance of a contact only (without deleting the entire contact)

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ssjs, mobileconnect, contact-deletion

The current deletion framework that was added last year does deletes entire contacts. A contact deleted this way is deleted from:

- All Contacts
- All Subscribers
- Mobile Connect

I have a problem where the cleanest solution would be to remove a problematic contact from Mobile Connect only (leaving the contact in All Subscribers and All Contacts).

Is there a way of doing this currently?

I can't seem to find anything like that in the Rest API and both Platform and Core functions.

---

*Update after using the endpoints pointed out by Rain.*

I used the `/contacts/v1/contacts/actions/delete?type=keys` endpoint with the following payload:

```
{  
   "ContactTypeId":0,
   "values":[  
      "ContactDeletionTest"
   ],
   "DeleteOperationType":"AttributesOnly",
   "optionValues":[  
      {  
         "adapterID":7014,
         "adapterKey":"ContactDeleteProcessor.MobileConnect",
         "values":[  
            {  
               "iD":"2f2e5b49-b2d3-4dad-8781-876bc9cd1525", 
               "value":"True"
            },
            {  
               "iD":"b0580712-a1fe-4bc0-9857-6dcfcd110439",
               "value":"True"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The two values in options.values represent `MobileConnectAddresses` and `MobileConnectSubscriptions` respectively.

With `"DeleteOperationType":"AttributesOnly"` and the email channel not mentioned anywhere, I posted this and my test contact got removed entirely (I've added a All Subscriber instance as well and it was deleted too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After presenting this problem to SF Support, an agent confirmed it's currently only possible to remove the entire contact:

> From consulting with our internal resources they clarified that
>   unfortunately the only valid/supported DeleteOperationType is the
>   current 'ContactAndAttributes', which is also the default one.
>   Therefore currently even when submitting a request with
>   DeleteOperationType as "AttributesOnly", the contact will be processed
>   as standard contact deletion, which is the full deletion of the
>   contact, including also Email Channel.

Answer (score 2):

Can't say if this will work, but when looking at [**getDeleteOptions**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getDeleteOptions.htm) there are two parameters called `ListType` and `ApplicationContext`. 
On the latter, there is the ApplicationID that can be provided.

Looking at the response there is the `adapterKey` with value `ContactDeleteProcessor.MobileConnect` that you'll probably need to target.

Eliot has posted [**an example**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132859/remove-users-from-all-contacts-in-marketing-cloud/183621#183621) calling both `ContactDeleteProcessor.ContactBuilder.Roots` and `ContactDeleteProcessor.MobileConnect` adapters together in the API call, so I would give a try (on some test Contact) by only targeting the adapter for MobileConnect through the `adapterID` attribute and see if that works.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. For some reason I thought this old endpoint was no longer active. I tried it out though and it also deleted my All Subscriber contact instance. I updated the case description to show the payload that should only remove the MobileConnect instance.